# I can't get the text from an URL (BeautifullSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to get info from the internet by a python script. Here it is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.es/Poco-NFC-Smartphone-Punch-Hole-Quad-c%C3%A1mara/dp/B08B9C149J/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=poco%2Bx3&qid=1600179415&quartzVehicle=16-179&replacementKeywords=poco&sr=8-3&th=1'


headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'}


page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find( id='productTitle').get_text()
```

The problem is that I'm getting none as a result of the ID 'productTitle' search when I should get the title I'm seing in the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you load a page in your browser, the browser will execute the JavaScript resources which may manipulate the page by adding elements to the DOM. Neither `requests` nor `BeautifulSoup` will exeucte this JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes but I have seen that with the same code people are getting the info I'm wanting to get.

Comment: Where did you see this code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=2s @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 1):

When going to the link provided in the code and then searching manually for "productTitle" in the HTML code, three results appear. The issue might be that you simply get the first result and therefor not the actual title. I am guesing you want the **span** with the **id=productTitle**. Try using

```
soup.find("span", id='productTitle').get_text()
```

Comment: Getting the first result would not be `None`.

Comment: Tried this but its not working. I think that the soup I'm getting is not expanded, so its not showing me the full title I need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the element with `id="productTitle"` doesn't exist in the content in the response. You can verify this by opening the Sources tab in Chrome or another browser. Press Ctrl+Shift+I and click on Sources at the top of the page. Expand `www.amazon.es` and the folder under it. Click on the file and press Ctrl+F and type "productTitle". It is not found.

You will also see that this page has a lot of JavaScript. Most likely when that code runs in the browser it adds elements to the DOM. When you use requests and BeautifulSoup, this JavaScript code is not executed so you won't get the exact same results as what you see in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically Amazon doesn't like bots going through there stuff. They put a sort of block on stuff like beautiful soup, selenium etc.
Have a look at the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050730/14166952

Comment: I have done that in my code. It's not working and I dont know why :S.